# Difference between notations in quotient spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a really basic question. What's the difference between this notation $V/\sim$ and $V/W$ where $V$ is a vector space and $W$ is a subset of $V$. I know that $V/\sim$ is the set of equivalence classes. But is $V/W$ the notation for the same thing? If so...what's the utility of this notation?

I know that $V/W$ is a subspace of $V$ if we define $\sim$ as $v_1 \sim v_2 $ if and only if $v_1-v_2 \in W$.

I have this bits of information, but I don't have the whole picture, could throw some light upon my understanding? Thx!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be exactly the same: the equivalence relation in the quotient space$\;V/\sim\;$  is defined **with respect to some subspace** $\;W\le V\;$: $\;u\sim v\iff u-v\in W\;$ , and we also denote this by $\;V/W\;$ , which becomes a linear *space* with the operations

$$\;(v_1+W)+(v_2+W):=(v_1+v_2)+W\;,\;\; k(v_1+W):P=kv_1+W\;$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are the same thing. It's useful because you can use it directly without defining $\sim$ (depending itself on $W$) beforehand.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. What does  squishing the size of the sub-set $W$ to zero? Referring to the definition of $\sim$.

Comment: I found this kind of explanation. But it didn't seem very clear to me!

Comment: @DenisNichita $W$ is a subspace. Smallest you can get is $W=\{0\}$ (which gives you the trivial quotient $V/W = V$).

Comment: Ok. I got that. And another question...
basically $V/W$ is a way of expressing the set of partitions of $V$? Since also the set  of equivalence classes forms a partition of $V$?

Comment: @DenisNichita If you want to see it in that way, $V/W$ can be considered as *one* partition of $V$ of a *very special form* (where each set of the partition is an equivalence class). Not all partitions can be interpreted as quotients, though. And I don't think it's a good way to visualize it, personally.